# Moving specific files by extension in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm very new to scripting in batch so please bear with me.

My goal is so as to move files which have the same filenames but with different extension; such as i want to move **myfile.txt.1** and **myfile.txt.2** without 'touching' **myfile.txt**
I've managed to use the wildcard * but it logically moves even the file which i don't want to move.(i.e. **myfile.txt**)

My question is... I was thinking of using a **for loop** to count files and using the "count" variable instead of the * , but is there a more direct way of implementing this script?

Attaching my script:

```
cd my_path
mkdir test 
robocopy "src" "dest" "my_file.*"
echo The file was moved succesfully !!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `robocopy` should be able to handle your needs.

I would have expected the wildcard `"my_file.txt.*"` to work, but interestingly it still matches `my_file.txt` despite the lack of a trailing `.`.

But adding the `/xf` option to exclude the "undecorated" filename works for me:

```
robocopy "src" "dest" "my_file.txt.*" /xf "my_file.txt"
```

Comment: yes that's what i've actually done... sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Interesting, you're right, that still doesn't work.  I've edited my answer, adding the `/xf` option.

Comment: Cheers Nate. When including the /xf the batch works as intended. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET sourcedir=c:\sourcedir
SET destdir=c:\destdir
FOR %%i IN ("%sourcedir%"\*.*) DO (
 FOR %%n IN ("%%~ni") DO IF NOT "%%~xn"=="" IF EXIST "%destdir%\%%~nxi" (
  ECHO CAN NOT MOVE "%%~fi" "%destdir%\%%~nxi"
 ) ELSE (ECHO MOVE "%%~fi" "%destdir%\%%~nxi")
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should accomplish the task AAUI. It also detects the presence of a clashing filename in the destination directory. Simply remove the `ECHO` from the `ECHO MOVE` to activate after verifying your test. Personally, I'd leave the `ECHO CAN NOT MOVE` as-is to report a problem. Changing that to `MOVE` has the potential to overwrite an existing file.